# Make my OSM database up to date again

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I have a cron job to run osmosis + osm2pgsql to keep my OSM database updated from https://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/day/

Due to problems in my server I have lost two weeks of update, working back again yesterday.

Now I have a gap in my data. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: I'd just redo the import from a new file.

Comment: Jesus! All the planet again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [history](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/full-history/2017/) folder, it has weekly files going back a month.

https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/full-history/2017/

Update:
I don't know if this will help you...  but based on the [wiki for Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis), you can "compare two planet dump files and produce a change set".  I would probably start with this process from the latest dump.

Comment: Humm... May I have problems if it import days I already have?

Comment: @MagnoC Sorry, I don't know enough about that.  But I've updated my answer to include more information.